# Method does not override package visible method in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings, visibility

From the Eclipse Java compiler setting: **Method does not override package visible method**

"A package default method is not visible in a different package, and thus cannot be overridden. When this option is enabled, the compiler will signal such scenario either as an error or a warning."

How can I trigger this Warning/Error? I'm looking for a code example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Foo.java:

```
package foopackage;

public class Foo {
    String getString() {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

#### Bar.java:

```
package barpackage;

import foopackage.Foo;

public class Bar extends Foo {
    String getString() {
        return "bar";
    }
}
```

Should do it.

From the [Eclipse Help docs](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/compiler/ref-preferences-errors-warnings.htm):

> A package default method is not visible in a different package, and thus cannot be overridden. When this option is enabled, the compiler will signal such scenario either as an error or a warning.

Comment: I wrote an equivalent test and it gave `method does not override or implement a method from a supertype` on the `@Override` line (at least with Sun javac 1.6.0_22). Removing the `@Override` annotation makes the example compile.

Your example needs imports btw.

Comment: @sjr Dont't put the annotation in and you'll get this error/warning instead. This is also a good example why using the `@Override` annotation is a good idea.

Comment: Did you test this? What javac version are you using? I don't get this behaviour: removing the annotation causes the example to compile.

Comment: @sjr: yeah, I wasn't doing this in an IDE or anything. Thanks.

Comment: @sjr: it's all about your compiler settings, specifically using Eclipse's compiler, and **not javac.**

Comment: Oh yea, @Override should always be used when it is valid to do so. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
package b;

public class Foo {

    void test() {}

}
```

And

```
package a;

import b.Foo;

public class Bar extends Foo {

    void test() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package a;

public class A {
    // package protected method foo : no visibility modifier
    void foo() {
    }
}

package b;

public class B extends A {
    // although this method has the same signature as A.foo(), it doesn't 
    // override it because A.foo is not visible to B (other package)
    void foo() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An example of why this warning or error is important consider the following example:

```
package a;

public class Animal { 

    // Note: no visibility modifier therefore package-private
    String makeNoise() {
        return "no noise defined";
    }
}

package b;

import a.Animal;

public class Cat extends Animal {

    // Note: Eclipse will show the warning that it doesn't override
    public String makeNoise() {
        return "meow";
    }

}

package b;

import a.Animal;

public class Dog extends Animal {

    // Note: Eclipse will show the warning that it doesn't override
    public String makeNoise() {
        return "bark";
    }

}

package a;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import b.Cat;
import b.Dog;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Make a list of Animals
        List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
        animals.add(new Cat());
        animals.add(new Dog());

        // Loop through the animals making their noises
        for (Animal animal : animals) {
            System.out.println(animal.makeNoise());
        }
    }

}
```

Copy paste the whole thing into Eclipse and it will sort out the classes and packages. Then run the `Main` class. You might expect it to print

```
meow
bark
```

But instead it prints

```
no noise defined
no noise defined
```

This is confusing behaviour which unexpectedly breaks polymorphism. The reason it does this is the `Animal` subclasses `Cat` and `Dog` have not actually overridden the method `makeNoise` at all, so when `makeNoise` is called on an `Animal` it uses the `Animal` implementation.

To fix this code add `public` or `protected` modifiers to the `Animal` `makeNoise` method, then rerun the code it will now work as expected. In this simple example its quite clear what is going on, but in a more complicated situation this behaviour could be extremely confusing and probably incorrect so the warning should be taken seriously.